# Telerik RadComboBox RenderingMode Simple

Tags: telerik, rendering

We are using a Telerik Rad ComboBox to render a drop down.  The issue is by default it renders a div and`<ul><li>` for the drop down list.  We tried setting the RenderingMode to "Simple" BUT for some reason the RenderingMode property is not taking.  We want the Simple property because it is SUPPOSED TO ouput:
`<select><option></option></select>`

instead it is still rendering 
`<ul> <li>`.
On mobile devices we want the list to pop up the device's default select option viewer.

We found that there is a property for the ComboBox to set RenderingMode="Simple", HOWEVER, it does not seem to be switching out our RadComboBox to  elements, it is keeping the default. I checked the HTML output in Firebug and nothing has changed.  The RadComboBox is inside a RadGrid that is triggered when "Add new record" selected. 
 Any reasons why setting the RenderingMode to Simple doesn't work???

EDIT

I see it rendering the select in Firebug and the style is pushed way left -9999 and the position if fixed, I overwrote the CSS so that those came into view BUT the values are not taking or inputting into our RadGrid when we click save.  It does not seem the items have the same values.

EDIT 2

Image 1. Even though we have RenderingMode="Simple" it still creates the 'ul li' version.

[image]

Image 2. It creates the HTML but according to the documentation the 'ul li' is supposed to be gone and the droplist is supposed to show up in place of it. Instead, as you can see in Firebug, it inputs BOTH.

[image]

Image 3. Shows both input types when I take the -9999px or the position fixed from the CSS can see both actually are rendered on the page
[image]

Image 4. Is the Code example. Very simple .Net using the RadComboBox with the RenderingMode specified but not working correctly.
[image: Code Example]

Comment: can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Yes I will add a few images that I sent to the Telerik guys (they have not gotten back to me yet). It will show Firebug and a few other things.

Comment: Added images to show my issue.